# Adding Elements To TinyCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to add a carousel to my site. I have looked around at the plugins available and come across TinyCarousel which is quite simple and light - what i'm after.

I have plugged in their code and followed their setup instructions and can successfully compile and run a carousel with some images.

A couple of issues im facing:

1) How can i modify their JS or CSS so that the size of the image is not so small? I have tried chaging the height and width in the **#slider1 .viewport class**, but no luck.

2) Once i can enlarge my images, i would like to add some kind of DIV that lays over the image, that contains a couple 'more info' hyperlinks to other pages on my site. The images in the carousel should still rotate, but the 'more info' DIV to stay put.

3) Is there any way i can place the **NEXT** and **PREV** buttons on top of the image? Like this - http://wowslider.com/slider-jquery-elegant-linear-demo.html  When the user hovers over the carousel, the **NEXT** and **PREV** buttons fade in.

I have attempted it here, please see my jsFiddle below

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<body>
<section id="welcome">
    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <section>
                <fieldset>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="slider1">  
                            <a class="buttons prev" href="#">left</a>
                            <div class="viewport">
                                <ul class="overview">
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://www.freestanding-kitchens.com/data/usr_001_collections/tables___chairs.jpg" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://www.pagazzi.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tables-and-chairs1.jpg" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <a class="buttons next" href="#">right</a>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1').tinycarousel({
       pager: true,
       interval: true
    });
});
```

Thanks

**Update Following resolution of issues 1**

New jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ginarann/JtfDd/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok these are the changes you need to do if you are setting up 640 x 640 sizes images.

```
 #slider1 .overview li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
        padding: 1px;
        height:640px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        width: 640px
    }
    #slider1 .viewport {
        float: left;
        width:640px;
        height: 640px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
```

2 . 
go like this. 
 for CSS.

```
 #slider1 .overview li span{
       position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 50px;

    }
    #slider1 .overview li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
        padding: 1px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        width: 400px;
    position :relative;
    }
```

for HTML

```
 <ul class="overview">
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://www.freestanding-kitchens.com/data/usr_001_collections/taes___chairs.jpg" />
                                        <span>Image description here 12345</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="http://www.pagazzi.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tables-d-chairs1.jpg" />
                                        <span>Image description here 2</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
```

1. the html for buttons is already set up 
   you only need the css

   ```
        #slider1 .buttons.prev{
     background-color:#333;
   }
   ```

   #slider1 .buttons.next{ 
       background-color:#333;
       }

customize these styles accordingly..

Comment: Thank you, but i am not trying to resize the images to fit in the box, i want them to be their true size, for example 600px 600px

Comment: Yes, that works - Thank you for your time! Are you able to help with issues 2 & 3 at all?

Comment: thanks again! Thats very close to what i am after, however, I am trying to have 'more information' sit over the image... and the image rotates underneath. So, the 'more info' DIVs/SPANs are static, and there is a carousel underneath just rotating images. Hope that makes sense. Appreciate your time. Update my fiddle with your amendments - http://jsfiddle.net/ginarann/JtfDd/17/

Comment: apologies, i was under the impression i needed 15rep to mark as answer, just realised that was for 'upping' :)

Comment: thanks for the update regarding the buttons. Any advice for  trying to have 'more information' sit over the image... and the image rotates underneath. So, the 'more info' DIVs/SPANs are static, and there is a carousel underneath just rotating images.

Comment: you can place the image and all other elements inside a DIV it will also work then.

Comment: I have tried placing a DIV under <div class="viewport"> with say for example <DIV> Contanst more information </DIV>, but no working.

Comment: <li><img src="img.jpg" /><div class="mycontent"> -- all your content here -- </div></li>
and change your class from  #slider1 .overview li span
to  #slider1 .overview li div.mycontent{ }

Comment: Thats nearly there!!! :D Rather than outlining multiple DIVs (or on each img), what im after is 1 DIV, that overlays the carousel. new fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ginarann/JtfDd/19/

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you very much for you time, effort and support :)

Comment: I have just notice din your Fiddle that the size of the carousel/images are set to 240x125px in the CSS. How can change this so that the carousl is 100% the size of my images? My images are a lot larger than 240x125 you see.

Comment: I think its these three classes - .maincontainer, #slider1 .overview li and #slider1 .viewport.. That require their Height and Width changing.. I have changed to 100% but still no luck.